# XNA/Monogame, Fastest way to draw multiple sheared/skewed sprites

Tags: 3d, xna, drawing, monogame, spritebatch

I normally work with `SpriteBatch` in XNA/Monogame for 2d games and have just recently delved into 3D drawing methods such as `DrawUserIndexedPrimatives` and the like. I'm working on a project where our animators would like to have the ability to shear sprites and textures.

With `SpriteBatch` you can pass in a matrix on `SpriteBatch` begin to shear an object. Something like:

```
//translate object to origin
Matrix translate1 = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-rectangle.X, -rectangle.Y, 0);

//skew the sprite 33 degrees on the X and Y axis
Matrix skew = Matrix.Identity;
skew.M12 = (float)Math.Tan(33 * 0.0174532925f);
skew.M21 = (float)Math.Tan(33 * 0.0174532925f);

//translate object back
Matrix translate2 = Matrix.CreateTranslation(rectangle.X, rectangle.Y, 0);
Matrix transform = translate1 * skew * translate2;

_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.NonPremultiplied,
                    SamplerState.PointWrap, DepthStencilState.Default,
                    RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null, transform);
_spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, rectangle, Color.White);
_spriteBatch.End();
```

The obvious down side of the this is that it requires you make a new `SpriteBatch` begin and end call for every sheared sprite. We currently only need 2 calls to `SpriteBatch` begin in our game. One for UI and one for World stuff. Our artist would want to use shear for stuff like swaying trees or animating legs and limbs on creatures so I could see that number jumping to 10+ separate batches if we gave them the option.

An average level has around 250 elements each containing 10-20 sprites.

I've written a test for Android that calls draw on 1000 sprites. Without any skewing it can draw all 1000, 600 times in about 11 seconds or approximately 53fps. But if I skew every tenth sprite (adding 100 new `SpriteBatch` call) it takes 47 seconds, or approximately 12fps.

That's really bad. Even for just 200 sprites (every tenth one skewed) the test drops to 28fps.

So I've also created the same test using Quads drawn with `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives`. Each Quad uses a shared `BasicEffect` created in the Game class and passed in via the `Sprite` classes constructor. I set the World Matrix and Texture before each `pass.Apply()` like so:

```
if (_basicEffect != null)
{
     foreach (EffectPass pass in _basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
     {
        _basicEffect.World = Transform;
        _basicEffect.Texture = _texture;
        pass.Apply();

        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives
            <VertexPositionNormalTexture>(
            PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
            _quad.Vertices, 0, 4,
            _quad.Indices, 0, 2);
}
```

For 1000 sprites, no skew, this gives me  12fps (I imagine it's like making 1000 `spriteBatch` calls). That's really bad. But for only 200 sprites with every 10th sprite skewed, I get 46fps which is significantly better than `SpriteBatch` (Even though I'm calling `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` like 200 times).

---MY QUESTION---

How could I batch my calls to `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` (or something similar) while keeping my sprites each contained in their own class that inherits `DrawableGameComponent`? That last parts pretty important just due to the nature of our game engine and the way it handles animation and collision and stuff.

I've read what I can about Vertex Buffers and `DrawIndexedPrimitives`, but don't quite have my head wrapped around it, and don't know how I'd assign new textures and world transforms to sprites drawn in this way.

Should I expect similar/better performance than `SpriteBatch` if I batch these calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me you have a couple of options, here.  Note that I'm primarily familiar with XNA 4.0 on the PC, so not all of these may be possible/performant in your case.

**The Easy, Hacky Way**

You don't appear to be using the color channel when drawing your sprites; this technique assumes that your example is representative of your real code.

If you don't need the sprite color for tinting your sprites, you can hijack it as a way to pass per-sprite data into a custom vertex/pixel shader.  For example, you could do this:

```
var shearX = MathHelper.ToRadians(33) / MathHelper.TwoPi;
var shearY = MathHelper.ToRadians(33) / MathHelper.TwoPi;
var color = new Color(shearX, shearY, 0f, 0f);
_spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, rectangle, color);
```

This represents the x- and y-shear values as factors of `2 * pi` stored in the red and green color channels, respectively.

Then you can create a custom vertex shader that retrieves these values and performs the shearing calculations on the fly.  See Shawn Hargreaves's article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) for information on how to do that.

**Hybrid Approach**

Another relatively straightforward possibility is to combine traditional sprite batching with your `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` code.

The key to good performance is to minimize state changes, so careful ordering of your sprites can go a long way.  Organize your sprites such that you can draw all non-skewed sprites in a single pass using `SpriteBatch`, then only use the slower `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` technique to draw the sprites that actually need it.  This should significantly reduce the number of batches being sent to the GPU, assuming that most of the sprites in a given frame aren't skewed.

**Batching + Custom Vertex Format**

This is probably the best technique, but it also involves writing the most code.  Not that any of it is particularly complex.

The way `SpriteBatch` works internally is that it maintains a dynamic vertex buffer which is populated on the CPU and then drawn all in a single call.  Shawn Hargreaves provides a high-level overview of how this sort of thing is done [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/07/07/setdataoptions-nooverwrite-versus-discard.aspx).

The problem with extending your `DrawUserIndexedPrimitives` to use this technique is that pesky world matrix; shaders don't really have a good way to attach a particular world matrix to a particular sprite (unless you're using hardware instancing, which I don't think your platform supports).  So what can you do?

If you create a custom vertex format, you can attach shearing values to each vertex, and use those to perform the shearing in the vertex shader, as in the first technique.  This will allow you to draw all of your game's sprites in a single call, which should be very fast.

You can find information on custom vertex declarations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb976065.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first technique won't work for us, as we'll need that color channel, but it is quite neat.

The second technique isn't bad but I still have to beign and end SpriteBatch several times as we're sorting stuff on the Y-axis for that 3/4 rpg type view.

The third option sounds like what we want, but I still haven't really wrapped my head Vertex Buffers and the like. If I have a 100 different sprites with different textures, or 100 different textures on as spritesheet. How do you specify what textures correspond to what vertices? Could you point me to a good tutorial?

Comment: You're going to want to use a single texture on a spritesheet.  Swapping textures requires a state change, which prevents draw calls from being batched.  Vertices can be assigned texture coordinates, which determine what part of the texture is drawn on them.  The MSDN has a basic tutorial on drawing textured quads; it uses one of the built-in vertex formats, but it should get the idea across: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051(v=xnagamestudio.10).aspx

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I think incorrectly understood how Texture Coordinates worked and it was confusing me. Thanks.